# Processing: Draw vector instead of pixels

Tags: vector, processing, pixel

I have a simple Processing Sketch, drawing a continuous line of ellipses with a 20px diameter. Is there a way to modify the sketch so that it draws vector shapes instead of pixels?

```java
  void setup() {
  size(900, 900); 
  background(110, 255, 94);  

} 

void draw() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
 fill(255);
}
```

Thanks to everyone who can provide some helpful advice.

Comment: Can you please clarify ? "drawing a **continuous** line of ellipses with a 20px diameter" - if your mouse moves faster, with your current implementation the line will not be continuous. Regarding vector shapes, you are drawing them as shapes. You can save these shapes in vector format using the [built-in PDF library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/index.html)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks, thanks, thanks for your quick response, a usual. My apologies for phrasing unclearly, by continuously I merely meant that the program keeps on drawing as I move the mouse. The gaps which occur due to moving the mouse pointer faster aren't really an issue at the moment.

Comment: Cool, in that case your program above already does what you need it to :D You simply need to add the pdf export functionality detailed bellow. It's also in one of the built-in examples: *Processing > Examples > Libraries > PDF Export > MousePress*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment above, there a couple of things to tackle:

1. > drawing a continuous line of ellipses with a 20px diameter
2. > draws vector shapes

Currently you're drawing ellipses based on mouse movement. 
A side effect is that if you move the mouse fast enough you will have gaps in between ellipses.

To fill the gaps you can work out the distance between every two ellipses.
If the distance is greater than the sizes of these two ellipses you can draw some in between.

The PVector class provides a lerp() function that allows you easily interpolate between two points.
You can read more on this and run some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923076/walk-along-pshape-contours-and-divide-them/39935273#39935273)

Using the ratio between these distance of two points and the ellipse size the number of points needed in between.
Here is an example that stores mouse locations to a list of PVectors as you drag the mouse:

```
//create an array list to store points to draw
ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();
//size of each ellipse
float size = 20;
//how tight will the extra ellipses be drawn together
float tightness = 1.25;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
} 

void draw() {
  background(110, 255, 94);
  fill(255);

  //for each point in the path, starting at 1 (not 0)
  for(int i = 1; i < path.size(); i++){

    //get a reference to the current and previous point
    PVector current  = path.get(i);
    PVector previous = path.get(i-1);

    //calculate the distance between them
    float distance = previous.dist(current);

    //work out how many points will need to be added in between the current and previous points to keep the path continuous (taking the ellipse size into account) 
    int extraPoints = (int)(round(distance/size * tightness));

    //draw the previous point
    ellipse(previous.x,previous.y,size,size);

    //if there are any exta points to be added, compute and draw them:
    for(int j = 0; j < extraPoints; j++){

      //work out a normalized (between 0.0 and 1.0) value of where each extra point should be
      //think of this as a percentage along a line: 0.0 = start of line, 0.5 = 50% along the line, 1.0 = end of the line
      float interpolation = map(j,0,extraPoints,0.0,1.0);

      //compute the point in between using PVector's linear interpolation (lerp()) functionality
      PVector inbetween = PVector.lerp(previous,current,interpolation);

      //draw the point in between
      ellipse(inbetween.x,inbetween.y,size,size);
    }

  }

  //draw instructions
  fill(0);
  text("SPACE = clear\nLEFT = decrease tightness\nRIGHT = increase tightness\ntightness:"+tightness,10,15);
}

void mouseDragged(){
  path.add(new PVector(mouseX,mouseY));
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == LEFT)  tightness = constrain(tightness-0.1,0.0,3.0);
  if(keyCode == RIGHT) tightness = constrain(tightness+0.1,0.0,3.0);
  if(key == ' ') path.clear();
}
```

Note that the interpolation between points is **linear**.
It's the simplest, but as the name implies, it's all about lines:
it always connects two points in a straight line, not curves.

I've added the option to control how tight interpolated ellipses will be packed together. Here are a couple of screenshots with different tightness levels. You'll notice as tightness increases, the lines will become more evident:

[image: tightness 0]

[image: tightness 1.5]

[image: tightness 3.0]

You run the code bellow:

```js
//create an array list to store points to draw
var path = [];
//size of each ellipse
var ellipseSize = 20;
//how tight will the extra ellipses be drawn together
var tightness = 1.25;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900);
} 

function draw() {
  background(110, 255, 94);
  fill(255);
  
  //for each point in the path, starting at 1 (not 0)
  for(var i = 1; i < path.length; i++){
    
    //get a reference to the current and previous point
    var current  = path[i];
    var previous = path[i-1];
    
    //calculate the distance between them
    var distance = previous.dist(current);
    
    //work out how many points will need to be added in between the current and previous points to keep the path continuous (taking the ellipse size into account) 
    var extraPoints = round(distance/ellipseSize * tightness);
    
    //draw the previous point
    ellipse(previous.x,previous.y,ellipseSize,ellipseSize);
    
    //if there are any exta points to be added, compute and draw them:
    for(var j = 0; j < extraPoints; j++){
      
      //work out a normalized (between 0.0 and 1.0) value of where each extra point should be
      //think of this as a percentage along a line: 0.0 = start of line, 0.5 = 50% along the line, 1.0 = end of the line
      var interpolation = map(j,0,extraPoints,0.0,1.0);
      
      //compute the point in between using PVector's linear interpolation (lerp()) functionality
      var inbetween = p5.Vector.lerp(previous,current,interpolation);
      
      //draw the point in between
      ellipse(inbetween.x,inbetween.y,ellipseSize,ellipseSize);
    }
    
  }
  
  //draw instructions
  fill(0);
  text("BACKSPACE = clear\n- = decrease tightness\n+ = increase tightness\ntightness:"+tightness,10,15);
}

function mouseDragged(){
  path.push(createVector(mouseX,mouseY));
}
function keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == 189)  tightness = constrain(tightness-0.1,0.0,3.0);
  if(keyCode == 187) tightness = constrain(tightness+0.1,0.0,3.0);
  if(keyCode == BACKSPACE) path = [];
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673192/processing-draw-vector-instead-of-pixels
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you want smoother lines you will need to use a different interpolation such as quadratic or cubic interpolation. You can start with existing Processing functions for drawing curves such as [curve()](https://processing.org/reference/curve_.html) or [bezier()](https://processing.org/reference/bezier_.html),and you'll find some helpful resources unrelated to  Processing [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/392606/line-drawing-how-can-i-interpolate-between-points.html),[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31859/Draw-a-Smooth-Curve-through-a-Set-of-2D-Points-wit) and [here](http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html).

**On vector shapes**

You're not directly working with [pixels[]](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html), you're drawing shapes.
These shapes can easily be saved to PDF using [Processing's PDF library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/index.html)
Check out the **Single Frame from an Animation (With Screen Display)** example.

Here is a version that saves to PDF when pressing the 's' key:

```
import processing.pdf.*;

//create an array list to store points to draw
ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();
//size of each ellipse
float size = 20;
//how tight will the extra ellipses be drawn together
float tightness = 1.25;

//PDF saving
boolean record;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);

} 

void draw() {
  background(110, 255, 94);
  fill(255);

  //if we need to save the current frame to pdf, begin recording drawing instructions
  if (record) {
    // Note that #### will be replaced with the frame number. Fancy!
    beginRecord(PDF, "frame-####.pdf"); 
  }

  //for each point in the path, starting at 1 (not 0)
  for(int i = 1; i < path.size(); i++){

    //get a reference to the current and previous point
    PVector current  = path.get(i);
    PVector previous = path.get(i-1);

    //calculate the distance between them
    float distance = previous.dist(current);

    //work out how many points will need to be added in between the current and previous points to keep the path continuous (taking the ellipse size into account) 
    int extraPoints = (int)(round(distance/size * tightness));

    //draw the previous point
    ellipse(previous.x,previous.y,size,size);

    //if there are any exta points to be added, compute and draw them:
    for(int j = 0; j < extraPoints; j++){

      //work out a normalized (between 0.0 and 1.0) value of where each extra point should be
      //think of this as a percentage along a line: 0.0 = start of line, 0.5 = 50% along the line, 1.0 = end of the line
      float interpolation = map(j,0,extraPoints,0.0,1.0);

      //compute the point in between using PVector's linear interpolation (lerp()) functionality
      PVector inbetween = PVector.lerp(previous,current,interpolation);

      //draw the point in between
      ellipse(inbetween.x,inbetween.y,size,size);
    }

  }
  //once what we want to save has been recorded to PDF, stop recording (this will skip saving the instructions text);
  if (record) {
    endRecord();
    record = false;
    println("pdf saved");
  }

  //draw instructions
  fill(0);
  text("SPACE = clear\nLEFT = decrease tightness\nRIGHT = increase tightness\ntightness:"+tightness+"\n's' = save PDF",10,15);
}

void mouseDragged(){
  path.add(new PVector(mouseX,mouseY));
}
void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == LEFT)  tightness = constrain(tightness-0.1,0.0,3.0);
  if(keyCode == RIGHT) tightness = constrain(tightness+0.1,0.0,3.0);
  if(key == ' ') path.clear();
  if(key == 's') record = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to George's great answer (which I've +1'd), I wanted to offer a more basic option:

The problem, like George said, is that when you move the mouse, you actually skip over a bunch of pixels. So if you only draw ellipses or points at `mouseX, mouseY` then you'll end up with gaps.

**The dumb fix:** the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables hold the previous position of the cursor.

That might not sound very useful, but they allow you to solve exactly your problem. Instead of drawing ellipses or points at the current mouse position, draw a **line** from the previous position to the current position. This will eliminate any gaps in your lines.

```
void draw(){
 line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY); 
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on getting user input in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input).

**Note:** This dumb solution will only work if you **aren't** redrawing the background every frame. If you need to redraw everything every frame, then George's answer is the way to go.