# p5.js canvas drawing path with ellipses

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, p5.js

I am working on a real time canvas drawing webapp using socket.io, node.js, and p5.js. I am having trouble creating a smooth line when the mouse is dragged. If the mouse is dragged too fast there is a trail of empty space in between each ellipse. The end goal here is to create a smooth path. Here are the things I have tried so far:

Attempt 1:

```
noStroke();
fill(lineColor[0],lineColor[1],lineColor[2]);
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, lineThickness, lineThickness);
```

Attempt 2:

```
strokeWeight(lineThickness);
line(mouseX,mouseY);
stroke(lineColor[0],lineColor[1],lineColor[2]);
```

Here is a picture of what the issue looks like:
[canvas drawing incomplete path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwdYB.png)

any feedback is welcome; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables, which hold the previous position of the cursor. Use that to draw a line from the previous position to the current position to fill in the blank space between mouse events.

From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pmouseX):

```js
// Move the mouse across the canvas to leave a trail
function setup() {
  //slow down the frameRate to make it more visible
  frameRate(10);
}

function draw() {
  background(244, 248, 252);
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  print(pmouseX + " -> " + mouseX);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/0.5.11/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answer is great because it will be more efficient to draw lines instead of many ellipses. You should also look into:

- [beginShape()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape)/endShape()
- [bezierVertex()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/bezierVertex)
- [curveVertex()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curveVertex)
- [curvePoint()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curvePoint)

The above should help you draw a smooth path and setting a thicker stroke will looks as it many filled ellipses are connected forming the path.

If for some reason you do want to draw many ellipses, you can interpolate position when the mouse move faster and create gaps to fill those gaps. 
For more information and p5.js example, check out this answer: 
[Processing: Draw vector instead of pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673192/processing-draw-vector-instead-of-pixels/40677300#40677300)